# ElementaryOS Loki - window shadow offset

Tags: tweak-tool

I am using ElementaryOS Loki and installed Tweaks also but unlike ElementaryOS Luna, I cannot increase the window shadow offset.

Is there a way to increase the window shadow offset in Loki ?

Answer (score 3):

Install dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Now start

```
dconf-editor
```

Goto org->pantheon->desktop->gala->shadows

You can change values here. Not all windows are effects. Looks like not allow windows can change shadow settigs from this location but many applications do pick up shadow settings from here